# Access to Grafana page directly from local login page

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, authentication, grafana

I'm trying to access Grafana metrics dashboard without using supported login form from Grafana. I just want users to go directly with authenticated Grafana page..

I have built login form(passport-local strategy) by using express in Node.js with connecting mongoDB to manage users, and try to connect to Grafana directly with session that I used but didn't work well.

Is there any ways to do this..?

I found one blog from raintank but I don't understand what he says because I'm new to server and all that stuff..

I just set it like below for now.

```
app.get('/grafana', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  console.log('Accessing to grafana');
  res.redirect('http://localhost:8080');
});
```

localhost:8080 is my Grafana page, and it still wants users to login again.

Hope my explanation is clear..

Thank you.

Comment: [Automatic Authentication using Grafana API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389522/automatic-authentication-using-grafana-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you have posted above only redirects the user to the local running graphana server and will not login the user automatically as redirect() just redirect from current url to another url, just like browsing to another url from a webpage.

You will have to use this [document](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/http_api/#create-api-token) for reference to create a API-token key and make a API call to grahana local server instance running.

And if you are planning to embed the graphana dashboard I would suggest using an iframe and you will have to give option for user to login again .

All this said I would strongly suggest against all this ,as this is not secure at all.
Please have a read through [this issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752)

OR

It is worth taking look at this document http://docs.grafana.org/reference/sharing/#embed-panel

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try out with API calls even it is not secure at all. I might try and push myself to learn :) Once again thank you! :)

Comment: Can I ask question about making an API call to grafana?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you.. I edited below as making an API call to grafana local server but doesn't authorized..

var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/dashboards/db/test';
var myToken = 'Token is gotten from Grafana';
request.get(url,{
    auth: {
      bearer: myToken
    }
  });

Comment: Actually I posted another question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545857/how-to-make-api-call-using-api-token-in-node-js-using-express-passport-local

Comment: Yes, But I think this is not going to get you what you want ,if you are looking to grafana dashboard directly in your  app. You might have to try something like mentioned in issue above https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3752

 _adding a javascript that automatic login to grafana, but is a temporal solution_

.......

or worth taking look at this document http://docs.grafana.org/reference/sharing/#embed-panel

Comment: @dmitj07 I see thanks alot for helping me out... ha... This is so hard for me... :'( I have to study to understand everthing I think...